# What is hot raspberry puree?

Tags: fruit, caramel, raspberries, puree

I have a caramel recipe that calls for hot raspberry puree to be added near the end of cooking. I'm assuming that the seeds are supposed to be removed, so how is this different from raspberry juice?

I have a bag of frozen raspberries. Could I just thaw them and put them through a mesh sieve (the way I would make juice)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raspberries aren't just seeds and juice, though they're certainly not as fleshy as some fruits. The difference between apple puree (apple sauce) and apple juice is much more obvious. In any case, you should be fine forcing them through a sieve as you suggest.

Comment: I would wazz them in a blender/food pro first, then pass through a sieve to remove seeds. This way you get more of the flesh, resulting in a puree instead of a juice.

Comment: @daniel: I guess I was thinking of the sieve I have, which I expect (with a bit of rubbing around) would let most of the flesh through too. You're right, of course, though!

Answer (score 2):

Combine 10oz frozen raspberries, 2 tablespoons sugar, 2 tsp cornstarch, and 1/2 cup water. Bring to boil, and continue boiling 5 minutes, or until sauce is thick. Strain sauce through a mesh strainer to remove seeds. Then you have hot raspberry puree (which is sweet) -- otherwise, remove the sugar.

Source: I made it once using [this recipe](http://allrecipes.com//Recipe/white-chocolate-raspberry-cheesecake/Detail.aspx).

Comment: Interesting, but I doubt that there is supposed to be either cornstarch or sugar. I'm pretty sure this recipe is looking for just raspberry.